# Need to create a regex Pattern to search in a flat file

Tags: regex

I need to a regex Pattern to filter the value from the flat file.

 Below is the content of the flat file

```
FILE myapps/abc/dfe/asd123123/sad/myfile_taskmenu.xml ABCD123:234234:AAS234:1
FILE efgh/qwe/advd123123/bad/myfile1.xlf C03858:BC4E4A:1
FILE myapps/efgh/qwe/advd123123/bad/myfile1.xlf C03858:BC4E4A:1
FILE myapps/abc/dfe/asd123123/sad/checkthis.xml WEOUIW:234234:AAS234:1
FILE myapps/yry/hjkyi/qweq/tyu/somefile_taskmenu.xml EWEF123SSD:234WEEDWE234:AASJH234:1
FILE myapps/werwer/qhjk12/wqerwe/ghj23/somefile.xlf SD2345:234JLH:HASDG:1
DIR  myapps/yry/hjkyi/qweq/tyu/somefile_taskmenu.xml EWEF123SSD:234WEEDWE234:AASJH234:1
```

From the above file content i need to filter the file path. The valid line numbers for the above file content are 1, 3, 5 and 6 i.e

```
myapps/abc/dfe/asd123123/sad/myfile_taskmenu.xml
myapps/efgh/qwe/advd123123/bad/myfile1.xlf
myapps/yry/hjkyi/qweq/tyu/somefile_taskmenu.xml
myapps/werwer/qhjk12/wqerwe/ghj23/somefile.xlf
```

Comment: So what do those four lines have in common that the other lines lack? Are you asking us to figure out what to look for? What exactly is your question?

Comment: What language/tool you're using for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
"^FILE\s+(myapps.*?(_taskmenu\.xml|\.xlf)) [A-Z0-9]*:[A-Z0-9]*:[A-Z0-9]*:1$"
```

That will work on the data that you provided. The path name will be in the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks for the pattern it works perfect but missed to match the 3rd line.. i.e 
FILE myapps/efgh/qwe/advd123123/bad/myfile1.xlf C03858:BC4E4A:1
where as the above pattern was able to match for the 6th line i.e 
FILE myapps/werwer/qhjk12/wqerwe/ghj23/somefile.xlf SD2345:234JLH:HASDG:1
So the pattern difference between 3rd and 6th line could be the path ends with String followed by a digit followed by .xlf 
But thanks a lot this will help me understanding the pattern.

Comment: Thanks i got the issue the 3rd line has only two alpha numeric with delimiter ":"
So it can be any number of alpha numeric characters delimited by ":" and end with digit \d

Comment: @user2589079: Then the last part of the pattern is "([A-Z0-9]*:)*\d$"

Comment: i tried with the below pattern and it worked for all the match
^FILE\s+(myapps.*?(_taskmenu\.xml|\.xlf)) [A-Z0-9:]*\d$

Comment: changing the last pattern as you suggest also works and it get one more group. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any suggestion for the below pattern
^FILE\s+(fusionapps.*[^build-]?(Ess\.xml)) [A-Z0-9:]*\d$
The above patter will get me lines that are Starting with FILE and contains 'fusionapps' followed by any character but should not contain word 'build-' or 'someword' and ends with Ess.xml. <br>
I am able to construct the patter but i am not able to add more than one word to ignore i.e build_ and someword

Comment: @user2589079: If you need help with another regular expression, post another question. Also, if this answer solved your problem, please click the check mark to accept the answer.